# Windows Outlook ignoring body container width

Tags: sass, outlook, zurb-foundation, html-email, newsletter

I'm going through testing my email newsletter, and everything seems to be working pretty solidly, except for windows outlook. It's working for osx outlook just not any version of windows. Basically outlook seems to ignore the main container and everything is spread out. It also is breaking styles, especially text and hr styles.

https://codepen.io/joefus1o4/pen/RyyyLL?editors=1000

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" style="background:#f3f3f3!important">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        @media only screen {
            html {
                min-height: 100%;
                background: #cacaca!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .small-float-center {
                margin: 0 auto!important;
                float: none!important;
                text-align: center!important
            }
            .small-text-center {
                text-align: center!important
            }
            .small-text-left {
                text-align: left!important
            }
            .small-text-right {
                text-align: right!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            table.body img {
                width: auto;
                height: auto
            }
            table.body center {
                min-width: 0!important
            }
            table.body .container {
                width: 95%!important
            }
            table.body .columns {
                height: auto!important;
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding-left: 16px!important;
                padding-right: 16px!important
            }
            table.body .columns .columns {
                padding-left: 0!important;
                padding-right: 0!important
            }
            table.body .collapse .columns {
                padding-left: 0!important;
                padding-right: 0!important
            }
            th.small-4 {
                display: inline-block!important;
                width: 33.33333%!important
            }
            th.small-6 {
                display: inline-block!important;
                width: 50%!important
            }
            th.small-12 {
                display: inline-block!important;
                width: 100%!important
            }
            .columns th.small-12 {
                display: block!important;
                width: 100%!important
            }
            table.menu {
                width: 100%!important
            }
            table.menu td,
            table.menu th {
                width: auto!important;
                display: inline-block!important
            }
            table.menu.vertical td,
            table.menu.vertical th {
                display: block!important
            }
            table.menu[align=center] {
                width: auto!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header .title {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header h2.text-right {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header th.month.small-6.large-6.columns.first {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header th.year.small-6.large-6.columns.last {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header th.small-6.large-4.columns.first {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header th.small-6.large-4.columns {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header th.small-6.large-4.columns.last {
                padding: 0!important;
                width: 100%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header hr {
                width: 100%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header .hr_3 {
                width: 100%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header p.text-left {
                margin-bottom: 0!important;
                padding-top: 4px!important;
                padding-bottom: 2px!important;
                padding-right: 8px!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header p.text-center {
                margin-bottom: 0!important;
                padding-top: 4px!important;
                padding-bottom: 2px!important;
                padding-left: 8px!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .header p.text-right {
                border: 0!important;
                margin-top: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .feature h2 {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:566px) {
            .feature h2 {
                font-size: 18px!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:448px) {
            .feature h2 {
                font-size: 15.5px!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .feature p {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .feature hr {
                width: 93%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .body-articles hr {
                width: 93%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .body-articles .wrapper-inner {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .video h2 {
                padding-left: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:419px) {
            .video h2 {
                font-size: 22px!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .video hr {
                width: 93%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .ad-social .OR_ad {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .ad-social h2 {
                padding: 0!important;
                font-size: 18px!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .ad-social p {
                padding: 0!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .ad-social .facebook {
                margin: 0!important;
                margin-bottom: 10px!important;
                width: 40%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .ad-social .instagram {
                margin: 0!important;
                width: 40%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .ad-social .linkedin {
                margin: 0!important;
                width: 40%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .ad-social .twitter {
                margin: 0!important;
                margin-bottom: 10px!important;
                width: 40%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .ad-social .youtube {
                margin: 0!important;
                width: 40%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:596px) {
            .ad-social hr {
                width: 93%!important
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width:495px) {
            .footer a {
                font-size: 13px!important
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;Margin:0;background:#f3f3f3!important;box-sizing:border-box;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;min-width:100%;padding:0;text-align:left;width:100%!important"><span class="preheader" style="color:#cacaca!important;display:none!important;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0;max-width:0;mso-hide:all!important;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden"></span>
    <table class="body" style="Margin:0;background:#f3f3f3!important;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;height:100%;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
        <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
            <td class="center" align="center" valign="top" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                <center data-parsed="" style="min-width:580px;width:100%">
                    <table align="center" class="container float-center" style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;margin:0 auto;padding:0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:580px">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                <td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                                    <table class="wrapper header" align="center" style="background:#8a8a8a;background-color:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                        <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                            <td class="wrapper-inner" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:20px;padding-top:40px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word">
                                                <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                            <hr class="hr_1" width="515" size="5" noshade="" style="background-color:#fefefe;border:0;border-top:5px solid;margin:0 auto">
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                            <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:16px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:564px">
                                                                <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                        <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                                            <center data-parsed="" style="min-width:532px;width:100%">
                                                                                <a class="OR_logo float-center" target="_blank" href="https://www.outdoorretailer.com/" align="center" style="Margin:0;color:#2199e8;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none"><img width="205" height="61" src="https://s15.a2zinc.net/Clients/EmeraldExpo/GlobalAdmin/CUSTOM/5_18_OR_Logo.jpg" alt="outdoor retailer logo" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border:none;clear:both;display:inline;max-width:100%;outline:0;padding-top:34px;text-decoration:none;width:auto"></a>
                                                                            </center>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th class="expander" style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0!important;text-align:left;visibility:hidden;width:0"></th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                            <th class="month small-6 large-6 columns first" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:16px;padding-right:8px;text-align:left;width:274px">
                                                                <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                        <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                                            <h2 class="title" style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:inherit;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:24px;font-weight:700;line-height:1.3;margin:0;margin-bottom:10px;padding:0;padding-left:6px;text-align:left;word-wrap:normal">MAY</h2></th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="year small-6 large-6 columns last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:274px">
                                                                <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                        <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                                            <h2 class="text-right" style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:inherit;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:24px;font-weight:700;line-height:1.3;margin:0;margin-bottom:10px;padding:0;padding-right:6px;text-align:right;word-wrap:normal">2018</h2></th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                            <hr class="hr_2" width="515" size="5" noshade="" style="background-color:#fefefe;border:0;border-top:5px solid;margin:0 auto">
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <table class="row" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;padding:0;position:relative;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                            <th class="small-6 large-4 columns first" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:16px;padding-right:8px;text-align:left;width:177.33px">
                                                                <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                        <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                                            <p class="text-left small-text-right" style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;border-right:1px solid;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:6px;padding:0;padding-bottom:4px;padding-left:8px;padding-top:6px;text-align:left">Summer Market</p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="small-6 large-4 columns" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;text-align:left;width:177.33px">
                                                                <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                        <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
                                                                            <p class="text-center small-text-left" style="Margin:0;Margin-bottom:10px;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:6px;padding:0;padding-bottom:4px;padding-top:6px;text-align:center">July 23-26, 2018</p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th class="small-6 large-4 columns last" style="Margin:0 auto;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 auto;padding:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:8px;padding-right:16px;text-align:left;width:177.33px">
                                                                <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:100%">
                                                                    <tr style="padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top">
                                                                        <th style="Margin:0;color:#0a0a0a;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left">
```

Comment: Please post your html code. Most likely the problem is that you need to add a `width="600"` to the table which sets the width of the email, since Outlook has a tendency to ignore the style sheet.

Comment: I've attached a code pen link with it. 

https://codepen.io/joefus1o4/pen/RyyyLL?editors=1000

Comment: I'm not wasting my day de-minifying your code to help you. I am positive I can help you, but why are you making people jump through hoops to do that? Post your code, properly formatted with your question.

Comment: My apologies. First time posting code or questions onto stack overflow. I believe the code should be correct now. The link is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your html code through Litmus and it looks fine with every version of Outlook Windows (2007, 2010, 2011, 2013, 2016, outlook.com, Outlook 365, Windows 10 mail). Their version of Outlook might be different than the version you're using to test.

My suggestion is to add `width="580"` to the table around line 308 which is the container. Outlook will respect a command like that, but sometimes ignore the `width:580px;` in the inline style sheet. The width in the table should not mess up your `@media` queries.

```
<table width="580" align="center" class="container float-center" 
style="Margin:0 auto;background:#fefefe;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;
float:none;margin:0 auto;padding:0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:580px">
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's odd that it's showing up fine for you in litmus. I'm still getting the same issue. The body is still going full screen. I'm using emails on acid, could it be possible it's an issue with them?

Comment: Litmus could be using a different version number of Outlook 2016 than the Email on Acid version of Outlook 2016. Microsoft has been making patches and working with Litmus to fix issues with Outlook.